# Using onSubmit with form in Featherlight?

Tags: javascript, jquery, featherlight.js

I am using Featherlight to display an HTML form and am not able to do the following:

1. Load the page with the form hidden initially.
2. Have the form's "onSubmit" fire when the form is submitted using a standard HTML submit button.

I call the inital lightbox manually as a global variable so I can use the "persist" option:

`lightboxForm = $.featherlight('#attendeeAddEditForm', { 'persist' : true });`

...but I can't seem to get the "beforeOpen" syntax correct to prevent it from displaying:

`beforeOpen: function(event){return false}`

...doesn't work inside the above call.

Here is a simplified version of what I am trying to do:

http://jsfiddle.net/djwljr/JNsu6/142/

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Fiddle doesn't seem to be working. Any reason not to follow use the usual conventions (e.g. IDs not camelcased, etc...)?

Comment: Fiddle appears to be working for me now. No real reason for the lack of camelCase, but I changed it for consistency (was just the one ID). I have updated the fiddle.

Comment: Thanks :-)  I meant IDs should *not* be camelcased, but no worries. I like conventions

Answer (score 0):

First, you can set the persist option using `data-featherlight-persist="true"` if you prefer (same for all featherlight options).

Second, either you call `$.featherlight(...)` which will open a window immediately, or you bind a button with `$('.my-button').featherlight(...)` (or with `data-featherlight`). The second form will not open the dialog immediately, as you desire. I don't think you'll need `beforeOpen` at all.

Comment: Marc, thanks for the response. Using my current implementation shown in the JSFiddle (as opposed to inline binding,) what is the syntax to prevent the lightbox from opening?  Also, how can I trigger the onSubmit in the lightbox? (Should I change the input type to a button instead of a submit, and trigger the validation and submit in the JS?) Thanks for your help.